# Save the duration in my stopwatch in Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, dart

How can I save the `duration` in my stopwatch app so that when I open the app I continue from where I stopped ?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `SharedPreferences` easily.

You can save `Duration` of `stopwatch` via `SharedPreferences` and init your timer by value of that.